# crop uiimageview which is out of bounds of another view

Tags: iphone, ios, image, sdk, crop

I have an UIImaveView(red one) which I have rotated to 45°. In this I a drawed an UIImage with a gradient and places it above the beneath laying UIImageView. Because of I rotated it to 45° this UIImageView laps over my beneath UIImageView(the gray one).

So I wanted to crop this UIImageView that it fits in the top left corner, but not overlapping over the frame of the underlaying UIImageView. There should be options with drawing Paths etc., but I hope anybody has any simpler solution?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C89nP.png

**solution**

```
UIImageView *rotatedGradient = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, -20, 50, 50)];
[_underlayingImageView addSubview:rotatedGradient];
[_underlayingImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you should add your view (red) as a subview of the other view (grey) and then set the superview (grey) to `clipsToBounds = YES`, which will tell it that subviews are not permitted to draw outside of its frame.

If both views (red and grey) are subviews of some other view which represents the frame you're interested in, you can set `clipsToBounds = YES` on the common superview.

Comment: Yes, simple solution, did not think of it.